# CUDA int4 bitwise operations

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, bit-shift

I was wondering is there any available bitwise operations for CUDA's vector types like int4/int2? I see lot of aux functions in cutil_math.h, but no any bit (left/right shift) operations, so I could

```
int4 x;
x <<= 100;
```

Thank you.

Comment: I've tested it on my GPGPU (k40m) CUDA 9.0
```
main.cu(67): error: no operator "<<" matches these operands operand types are: int4 << int main.cu(71): error: no operator "|" matches these operands operand types are: int4 | int4
```
you can see the correct way to use the int4 as asked here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26676806/efficiency-of-cuda-vector-types-float2-float3-float4

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to do the operation element-wise (or define the operator yourself).

Comment: Yes, already implemented one :) But wanted to know if there is effective and tested implementation in CUDA SDK.